# Tube from Heathrow to King's Cross

Tags: train-stations

What is the Tube entrance called at Heathrow?  Is it in the airline terminal?  I am reading it is the Underground Station.

Comment: Which Heathrow terminal are you using?

Comment: You didn't specifically ask this, but just in case, when you take the Piccadilly line tube from Heathrow (it's the only line there, the display will probably say it goes to Cockfosters), you can just sit back and relax for 55 minutes until you arrive at King's Cross St. Pancras Underground Station.

Answer (score 21):

The tube or subway is called the **Underground**. A typical [direction sign](https://www.londontoolkit.com/lhr/heathrow_logistics.htm) within a terminal at Heathrow is shown below.

[image]

The London Underground logo is used everywhere in the signage.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

There are three stations:

- Heathrow Terminals 2&3
- Heathrow Terminal 4
- Heathrow Terminal 5

(Note that 2, 3, 4 and 5 are the only terminals: Terminal 1 closed a few years ago.)

The station for Terminals 2 and 3 is between the two terminals and is reached by clearly signposted pedestrian tunnels. The stations for 4 and 5 are in the corresponding terminal and, again, clearly signposted.

There is more [information on the airport website](https://www.heathrow.com/transport-and-directions/underground).